# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, runtime-error, tensorflow2.0

When ever I run this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.Tensor([[0, 1, 2, 3][3, 2, 1, 0]])
print(tensor.shape)
print(tensor.shape[0])
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "singlestock/code.py", line
>   1, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf   File "D:\documenten\programs\Python\3.7.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py",
>   line 98, in 
>        from tensorflow_core import *
>
> File
>   "D:\documenten\programs\Python\3.7.4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py",
>   line 40, in 
>        from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools';
>   'tensorflow.python' is not a package

I have tried to solve it by reïnstalling python and all packages. That didn't work.

I later tried to reïnstall all packages with the pip cache disabled, which also didn't work.

I also ran down all the code and seems like "module_util" is right there where it should be ("D:\documenten\programs\Python\3.7.4\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\tools\module_util.py").

This problem doesn't occur when importing other packages. It's only with Tensorflow.

So i don't get why python couldn't find that module.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Apparently you can't call your script "code.py". I changed the name and now it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You need to verify is the package installed there are two methods for that :

method 1:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

now for each output check and verify manually is the package installed

method 2:

```
try:
    import mymodule
except ImportError, e:
    pass
```

then if you find the package is missing kindly verify is it installed on the wrong place because might be possible you have more than one python installed.

and then manually put that library from downloading the files from the path
[tesnorflow](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/) and putting in the place we got from method 1

Comment: The package is installed on the right place, so this isn't the solution.

Comment: This is my sys.path: ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Programs\\Tensorflow\\singlestock', 'D:\\documenten\\programs\\Python\\3.7.4\\python37.zip', 'D:\\documenten\\programs\\Python\\3.7.4\\DLLs', 'D:\\documenten\\programs\\Python\\3.7.4\\lib', 'D:\\documenten\\programs\\Python\\3.7.4', 'D:\\documenten\\programs\\Python\\3.7.4\\lib\\site-packages']